# Display bash result via ajax

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, bash

So i am new to php and ajax. I am trying to run a file in terminal and then return the result to the client side. Everyting is working fine but result is not displayed on client side. I echoed the result and i can see it. php is working fine but i think my ajax is wrong. SOme help please.

This is my php code

```
<?php
if (isset ($_POST["list"]))
{   
$listval1 = $_POST["list"]; 
$myfile = fopen("list.c", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
fwrite($myfile, $listval1); 
fclose($myfile);
}

else
{
$output=shell_exec(' gcc /var/www/html/list.c');
//print_r($output);
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
//echo"success";

}
?>
```

This is my ajax code

```
jQuery("#list").click(function(){
console.log("button clicked");

jQuery.ajax({

url: "/simulation.php",

type: "POST",
data: {list:jQuery("#listarea").val()},
dataType: "html",


success: function() {
//console.log(data);
window.location = "/simulation.php" ;
} 
}, 


});


});
```

Comment: you declare the dataType as html are you returning an html response?if not then change the type to which type you are returning from ajax

Comment: @Pekka :can you please provide an example sorry i am new to this.

I provide data type as html to send the input values which are dumped in the list file. is that wrong

Comment: How can you know what the script returned? You just make the ajax call but don't process the result.

Comment: @amarnasan: echo "<pre>$output</pre>"   gives me the output hence i can see it is working but the problem is that it gets echoed. It simply runs the php and php displays the result. I want the result in the same page via a dialog box like how you download a file it asks you to save. I want the same thing to be done but just displaying the result.

Comment: @RAM sorry i didnt see the php echo so it is string right?the one you echo?so change the type to `text` and you should be ok

Comment: @pekka: its just the result of the file that is compiled. logs and result

Comment: you should return something to the UI part no matter what i suggest you return a string just echo it on success echo success and fail if otherwise and change the dataType to text and try again

Comment: @pekka: So i will tell you the whole process. So a user gives some input via form. That input is then posted to simulation.php via ajax which then creates a file and dumps that html data into it. Hence datatype html. Next thing what it does is that executes the bash command which is run on the server and takes that file as input reads it and gives output which is displayed.

Comment: @RAM so you display an `HTML` not a text sorry now i get it. dont accept my edit

Comment: @RAM what output does it give last question

Comment: @pekka: Normal c logs if error in input or the result as number or string. same as you compile in your terminal any c code

Comment: then just use dataType text. give it a try

Comment: @pekka: did that . no effect. I think there is some issue with my  window.location = "/simulation.php" ; :( anyidea how to display bash result via ajax on client side.

Comment: uncomment the console log and see what it displays.

Comment: @pikka: reference error data is not defined.

Comment: in `function()` you dont have data change it to `function(data)`

Comment: did that too got this error .  The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol.